# Reading doc, docx files from s3 within lambda

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, docx, doc

TLDR; reading with my AWS lambda `doc`, `docx` files that are stored on S3.

On my local machine I just use `textract.process(file_path)` to read both doc and docx files.

So the intuitive way to do the same on lambda is to download the file from s3 to the local storage (`tmp`) on the lambda and then process the `tmp` files like I do on my local machine.

That's not cost-effective...

Is there a way to make a pipeline from the S3 object straight into some parser like `textract` that'll just convert the `doc`/`docx` files into a readable object like `string`?

My code so far for reading files like txt.

```
import boto3

print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:  # Read s3 file
        bucket_name = "appsresults"
        download_path = 'Folder1/file1.txt'
        filename = download_path
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        content_object = s3.Object(bucket_name, filename)        

        file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

        print(file_content)

    except Exception as e:
        print("Couldnt read the file from s3 because:\n {0}".format(e))

    return event  # return event
```

Comment: `not cost-effective`, do you mean the lambda cost ? I am not sure about your monthly usage but you may be using lambda in the free tier.

Comment: by `not cost-effective` I mean that instead of ONLY reading the s3 file (which we have to do) We'll also save the file in local storage (which consumes time) and then load it (which also consumes time) @Ersoy

Comment: I understand, that's the normal behavior in any language. Afaik, there is no transformation/converter pipeline available on s3 by events.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer solves half of the problem**

`textract.process` [currently doesn't support reading file-like objects](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract/issues/157). If it did, you could have directly loaded the file from S3 into memory and pass it to the `process` function.

[Older version of `textract`](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.0/_modules/textract/parsers/docx_parser.html#Parser) internally used `python-docx` package for reading `.docx` files. `python-docx` supports reading [file-like](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.Document) objects. You can use the below code to achieve your goal, at least for `.docx` files.

```
import boto3
import io
from docx import Document

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
object = bucket.Object('/files/resume.docx')

file_stream = io.BytesIO()
object.download_fileobj(file_stream)

document = docx.Document(file_stream)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading the docx file from s3, Document() constructor expects path for the file. Instead, you can read the file in byte format and call the constructor like this.

```
from docx import Document

def parseDocx(data):
    data = io.BytesIO(data)
    document = Document(docx = data)
    content = ''
    for para in document.paragraphs:
        data = para.text
        content+= data
    return content

Key = "acb.docx"
Bucket = "xyz"
obj_ = s3_client.get_object(Bucket= Bucket, Key=Key)
if Key.endswith('.docx'):
    fs = obj_['Body'].read()
    sentence = str(parseDocx(fs))
```